# MYSQL Stored Procedure Issues

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am writing a MySQL Stored Procedure for the first time, and I am running into an issue - I think with the Handler Code. Basically, I want this code to update all rows in the `pps_users` table, but for some reason I am hitting the 'finished condition' for the handler after only two rows are fetched.

I tried the same thing with the REPEAT syntax and got the same result.  If I just run the cursor query I correctly get the 10,000 records I expect, but when I run the whole thing as is, I hit the finished code after only 1 or 2 records.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `changeNFLFavTeams`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE favNFLTeam varchar(100) DEFAULT "";    
    DECLARE favNCAATeam varchar(100) DEFAULT "";    
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE user_id bigint(20);
    DECLARE fullNameOfTeam varchar(100) DEFAULT ""; 
    DECLARE update_favs CURSOR FOR select id, favorite_nfl_team from pps_users WHERE favorite_nfl_team is not null;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;    
    OPEN update_favs;


    updaterecord: LOOP
    FETCH update_favs INTO user_id, favNFLTeam;

        select user_id, favNFLTeam as "Test";

        if v_finished = 1
        then
            select "finished" as "finished";
            LEAVE updaterecord;
        end if;

        select full_name into fullNameOfTeam
                                from teams t 
                                inner join display_names dt on dt.entity_id = t.id 
                                and dt.entity_type = 'teams' 
                                and dt.first_name = favNFLTeam
                                and team_key like 'l.nfl.com%' LIMIT 1;

    select user_id, fullNameOfTeam AS "BeforeUpdate";

            IF fullNameOfTeam != ''
            THEN
               -- here for whatever_transformation_may_be_desired
            -- Find the Full name for the record they chose
                UPDATE pps_users p
                SET favorite_nfl_team = fullNameOfTeam
               WHERE user_id = p.id;
            ELSE
                SELECT 'A' AS 'A'; -- no op
            END IF;  


  end loop updaterecord;

  CLOSE update_favs;

END
```

Comment: Is it possible that an error is being generated in some iteration of the LOOP?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the output when I run it - it looks like it is working ok.

Comment: If you process a smaller amount of records the problem persists?

Comment: Yes, I limited the IDs in the query to around 100 results and I am seeing the same thing.

Comment: Try testing piece by piece, first remove all the body LOOP, and proves that properly iterates over all records of the cursor. Is it possible to publish a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) test case, especially to have some data?

Answer (score 0):

This is because if your SELECT full_name into fullNameOfTeam... query returns no rows, then it will set v_finished to 1. That, apparently, happens early on, and forces an exit from the main loop.

The key is to realize that the CONTINUE HANDLER for NOT FOUND does not apply to the cursor alone.

You should either put the secondary query into its own BEGIN..END block with its own CONTINUE handler, or (easier) just set v_finished = 0 after the SELECT full_name into fullNameOfTeam... statement.